# Sentry.captureMessage() fails if location changes

Tags: javascript, sentry

If browser location changes (e.g., window.location.replace()), Sentry fails with

`Sentry Logger [error]: Failed while sending event: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource`

Is there no way to await the POST to the ingest?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are lacking but Sentry.flush() does give us a promise that can be awaited. So it might look like

```js
Sentry.captureMessage()
await Sentry.flush()
```